# Power BI summarizing transposed table that contains qualitative data/rows

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a table in PowerBI that has qualitative and quantitative columns, the first few being qual and then the rest being quant representing a value at a point in time. I am transposing the table so that each sample/title becomes its column for graphing. I can transpose the table, but it cannot be summarized if the qual rows (formerly cols) are not deleted; if I delete the qual rows, I can summarize the table and graph it, but I cannot filter it by the deleted qual rows. Is there a way to summarize the quant rows in the table but not the qual rows or to split the table into multiple and use relationships to achieve the desired effect?

Sorry if that was confusing, thank you in advance!

I have tried using the slicer and have tried to summarize the table when it has the qual rows and messing with relationships but neither have worked out so far.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself.

The order values are added to PowerBI is important, add the categorical values into the visual first then the numerical values. In the example code below, there is only 1 categorical value, and it doesn't display on the visual but is a filter for it. By including the categorical values in the visual but not showing them, you can use the slicer to filter the data by them and still have a transposed visual.

```
newData = dataset.T 
headers = newData.iloc[0]
newData = pd.DataFrame(newData.values[1:], columns = headers)
```

This is my second question and first answer, I hope you found this helpful if you are experiencing a similar issue.